# Why does Tensorflow's automatic differentiation fail when .numpy() is used in the loss function?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I've noticed that Tensorflow's automatic differentiation does not give the same values as finite differences when the loss function converts the input to a numpy array to calculate the output value. Here's a minimum working example of the problem:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def lossFn(inputTensor):
    # Input is a rank-2 square tensor
    return tf.linalg.trace(inputTensor @ inputTensor)

def lossFnWithNumpy(inputTensor):
    # Same function, but converts input to a numpy array before performing the norm
    inputArray = inputTensor.numpy()

    return tf.linalg.trace(inputArray @ inputArray)

N = 2
tf.random.set_seed(0)
randomTensor = tf.random.uniform([N, N])

# Prove that the two functions give the same output; evaluates to exactly zero
print(lossFn(randomTensor) - lossFnWithNumpy(randomTensor)) 

theoretical, numerical = tf.test.compute_gradient(lossFn, [randomTensor])
# These two values match
print(theoretical[0])
print(numerical[0])

theoretical, numerical = tf.test.compute_gradient(lossFnWithNumpy, [randomTensor])
# The theoretical value is [0 0 0 0]
print(theoretical[0])
print(numerical[0])
```

The function `tf.test.compute_gradients` computes the 'theoretical' gradient using automatic differentiation, and the numerical gradient using finite differences. As the code shows, if I use `.numpy()` in the loss function the automatic differentiation does not calculate the gradient.

Could anybody explain the reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the guide : [Introduction to Gradients and Automatic Differentiation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff#2_did_calculations_outside_of_tensorflow)

> The tape can't record the gradient path if the **calculation exits TensorFlow**. For example:
>
> ```py
> x = tf.Variable([[1.0, 2.0],
>                  [3.0, 4.0]], dtype=tf.float32)
>
> with tf.GradientTape() as tape:   
>   x2 = x**2
>   # This step is calculated with NumPy   
>   y = np.mean(x2, axis=0)
>   # Like most ops, reduce_mean will cast the NumPy array to a constant tensor 
>   # using `tf.convert_to_tensor`. 
>   y = tf.reduce_mean(y,axis=0)
>
> print(tape.gradient(y, x))
> ```
>
> outputs `None`

The numpy value will be cast back as a constant tensor in the call to `tf.linalg.trace`, which Tensorflow cannot compute gradients on.